# Simular entrada de teclado en un input con jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Nesito escribir texto dentro de un input simulando una pulsacion de teclado, no puedo usar .val() ni .text() ni nada de eso , la idea es llamando a $(input).trigger("keypres...  escriba dentro del input , pero  no hay manera alguna ayuda?

(editado)

ya he probado :

//deberia escribir la letra P

```
var press = jquery.Event("keypress");
press.ctrlKey = false; 
     press.which = 80;
     $("input").trigger(press);
```

---

```
$("input").trigger({type: 'keypress', which: 80, keyCode: 80});
```

---

```
var event = jquery.Event('keypress');
   event.which = 80; 
   event.keyCode = 80;
   $("input").trigger(event);
```

Nota:todo lo anterior ha sido probado con keypress , keydown y keyup
incluso haciendo antes un $("input").focus() y $("input").change() tras la ejecucion de trigger y nada , tampoco.

Comment: Añade lo que hayas intentado

Comment: He actualizado mi pregunta , gracias por responder

Answer (score 0):

Lo que intentas hacer es algo más parecido a esto:

```
$( "input" ).keyup(function() {
var texto = $('input').val();
 if(texto.indexOf('p') != -1){
    $('input').val(texto+'pp');
 }
});
```

En primer lugar activas el evento de "keyup" porque en "keypress" aún no habrá nada escrito en el input. Lo siguiente compruebas si el input tiene el valor que buscas y lo modificas como quieras.